# Jquery dynamic dropdown where query returns null values

Tags: php, jquery, sql, json

I have created a dynamic dropdown menu using an SQL server, jquery and PHP. The menu itself queries my database to select  a project then depending which project is  selected it initiates a selection of the tasks related to that project.

Some projects do not have any tasks assigned to them which returns a NULL value from the sql query.

The problem I face is that if I accidentally click on the wrong project and then wish to change the project back to one with no tasks it doesnt revert back to a null value. It works fine if  the projects returns other values.

Here is the script I have used:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$.getJSON("projects.php", success = function(data) 
{
var options = "";

for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++)
{
    options += "<option value='" + data[i].toLowerCase() + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>";
}

$("#slctProj").append(options);

 $("#slctProj").change(); 


});

$("#slctProj").change(function()
      {

        $.getJSON("tasks.php?projects=" +$(this).val(), success = function(data) 
             {
                    var options = "";

                    for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++)
                    {
                        options += "<option value='" + data[i].toLowerCase() + "'>" + data[i] + "   </option>";
                    }
                    $("#slctTask").html("");
                    $("#slctTask").append(options);
             });  

      });
```

});

Comment: try to debug in firefox that your ajax request request returns data every time you change dropdown

Comment: So what is the `data` in `success = function(data)` when your query returns null. It could be causing `data.length` in `for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++)` to error. Try checking if `data` is valid before trying to use it.